# Crear vidas en un juego de Python

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles

Acabo de crear un juego en el que se crea un número aleatorio y el usuario tiene que adivinar el número, quisiera saber qué debería hacer para que en el juego haya un sistema de vidas y en base a esas vidas le pida al usuario que siga intentando les dejo mi código

```
''' Programa en el que el usuario debe adivinar el número generado por la computadora'''
import random
rndnum = random.randint(1,10)
name = input("Dime tu nombre: ")
print("Hola,{} en este programa tendras que adivinar el número que ha generado la máquina entre 1 y 10".format(name))
n = int(input("introduzca un número: "))
if n == rndnum:
    print("Felicidades, has acertado")
else:
    print("No has adivinado, intenta otra vez")
```

soy algo nuevo en python y estoy aprendiendo por mi propia cuenta, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
'''Programa en el que el usuario debe adivinar el número generado por la computadora'''
import random
rndnum = random.randint(1, 10)
name = input("Dime tu nombre: ")
print("Hola,{} en este programa tendras que adivinar el número que ha generado la máquina entre 1 y 10".format(name))

maxVida = 3  # Numero maximo de vida
while maxVida != 0:
    n = int(input("introduzca un número: "))
    if n == rndnum:
        print("Felicidades, has acertado")
    else:
        maxVida = maxVida - 1
        print("No has adivinado, intenta otra vez")
```

**Explicación**

Para realizarlo debes usar ciclos (`for`, `while`), en te caso utilice un while, adicional agregue una variable `maxVida =3` que serán nueva máxima vida del juego, cada ves que pierdo `print("No has adivinado, intenta otra vez")` le resto una vida.

Y con el ciclo `while` ejecuto el código mientras la vida sea diferente de 0, que quiere decir que perdió.

Comment: Hola, implementé tu código y me funciono a la perfección solo un pequeño detallito, le quise añadir un msj al final si no adivinaba el número para que lo muestre (y así no quedar con la duda) al final del while que añadiste puse 
` if maxVida == 0:
    print("el número era {} :P".format(rndnum))` y aunque adivine el numero a la primera me sigue pidiendo que introduzca un número. Cómo solucionaria eso?

Comment: @P4Kubz Todo dependerá de la lógica tuya, como yo lo solucionaría:

Una variable de tipo “switch”, que me ayudara a controlar cuando el jugador adivine el número.
sw = 0
Agregaría una condición en while(maxVida != 0 and sw != 1)  y el if debo cambiar el valor de la variable sw = 1. Luego fuera del while compruebo si el sw == 0 quiere decir que perdió y le mostraría el mensaje con el numero aleatorio

Answer (score 0):

la forma mas facil de hacerlo es con un ciclo while

```
vida= 3 #definimos el numero de vidas
while intentos>0:
     jugador = input('ingrese el numero ')
     if int(jugador) == rndnum: #verificamos si es igual  al numero random
          print('felicitaciones has adivinado el numero')
          break 
     else:
          vida-=1 #si fallo le quitamos una vida
          print('Vuelve a intentarlo')
```

no te olvides de convertir el numero obtenido del input a un entero o tendras un error.